# Show Bar graph at bottom of div box

Tags: d3.js

How do I center the bar graph inside that has the class "inner-container"? It doesn't show the full bar as shown in the div with id "bar2".

[Here](https://bl.ocks.org/centem/1623ba91f7bdaf2636c578e9ed93d3c4) is the full bl.ocks. Thank you.

Comment: Use Scales: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

Comment: Thank you for responding rioV8. It looks like he is using scales on the axis. I don't have axis. Where would I apply scales?

Comment: No Axis use scales. Look closely at the height and position calculation of the rects. Don't hard code the position use `d3.scaleLinear`